# Cannot get people to connect to me

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, minecraft

I am trying to set up a minecraft server on a pc that I have just upgraded from, which I have decided to run linux on.
My usage of linux is rough but I feel like people should be able to connect to me. I have allowed the default minecraft port (25565) in the UFW and have forwarded the port from my modem to my router, and from the router to the pc. My friends can connect to me when I host on my now main pc (of course I have to change the router port forward to the ipv4 of this machine), so I know the port forward works. While hosting on my main pc (which is running windows) I can use port checking sites to check my public IP and port 25565 and they say its running, however when running the server on the Ubuntu machine they say closed (or in one case "filtered") [UFW status showing that port 25565 is allowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWDaE.png) 
[Netgear router page showing the portforward](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyaHj.png) [Xfinity Gateway/modem showing the port forwarding to the router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hApce.png)

Edit: I'm using an SSH to execute terminal commands and team viewer to transfer files

Comment: Hi Nick. Can you connect your Windowsmachine to your Minecraftserver?

Comment: Yes, I can use the ipv4 address of the server machine to connect to it from my windows pc.